# How do I create a woocommerce product title based on whether a variable exists or not using function.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with a woocommerce website with a function.php file that I edit within a plugin called WP All Import. It's linked to a plugin that imports csv & xml files.

In WP All Import I set the import title as [product_title({product_name[1]}, {size[1]}, {colour[1]})] and it picks up the items from an import.

What I'm trying to do is set the product name as a combination of variables. So in the example below, if both $size and $colour are empty I want the product name to just be $name. If $size is empty, then $name - $colour. If $ colour is empty then $name - $size. And then if they all have values $name - $colour - $size.

```
function product_title($name, $size, $colour)
{
    $newName = $name;
    
    if (strpos($size, "")) {
        if (strpos($colour, ""))
    {
        $newName = "$name";
    }
    }   
    else if (strpos($size, ""))
    {
        $newName = "$name - $colour";
    }
    else if (strpos($colour, ""))
    {
        $newName = "$name - $size";
    }
    else
    {
        $newName = "$name - $colour - $size";
    }   
}
```

At the moment this is leaving the titles as blank. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this not so long ago. It's pretty tricky to understand. In short you can't use [pre_get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) because the terms are not set yet. You must use `save_post` with `wp_update_post`, but there is a few thing to understand like the [infinite loop case](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#avoiding-infinite-loops).

Don't hesitate to adapt it. I guessed that `colors` and `sizes` are custom taxonomies, just make sure the slugs matches. Modify it and have fun.

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'worker', 10, 3 );
function worker( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

  // ... if not the admin side or if user can't edit post, then bail
  if ( ! is_admin() || ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;

  $worker = ( object ) [
    'post_type' => 'product',   // ... set our taxonomy in your case, "product"
    'taxonomies' => [ 'colour', 'size', ], // ... set the taxonomies that we want to use in our title
  ];

  // ... if not a post.php page or post-new.php page, then bail
  $base = [
    'post.php',
    'post-new.php',
  ];
  if( ! in_array( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' ), $base, true ) && $post->post_type != $worker->post_type )
    return;

  // ... do not update title if autosave
  if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

  // ... fetch our terms and join them
  $terms = join( ' - ', wp_list_pluck( wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $worker->taxonomies ), 'name' ) );

  // ... define our title structure
  $self = $post->post_title . $terms . '#' . $post_id; // ... You should leave the post_id as a unique identifer, so you don't end up with 2 product with the same title

  // ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#avoiding-infinite-loops
  remove_action( 'save_post', 'worker' );

  wp_update_post( array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_title' => esc_attr( $self ),
    'post_name' => sanitize_title( $self ),
  ) );

  add_action( 'save_post', 'worker', 10, 3 );

}; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @amarinediary. So this almost, kind of, worked. But instead of colour and size in the title it put the post ID there twice. Separated by a '-'.

Comment: Have you updated the slug to match yours ? It's working on my end ... Are size and colors custom taxonomies ?

Comment: They are product attributes.